# Nao recebo nada do php no android

Tags: php, android, json

Bom tarde eu tenho um problema. Eu consigo ir buscar a informação toda que tenho na tabela, mas ao alterar o codigo para que so me apareça a informação de uma determinada pessoa da erro e não retorna valor nenhum valor para o android. Eu sou novo no android por isso ajudem por favor. Se puderem postem o codigo corrigido Obrigada.

Codigo PhP funcional (Retorna toda a tabela(não é esse o objetivo)):
Aqui funciona:
 O log: jsonResult:﹕ {"info":[{"NProcesso":"467","DataConsulta":"11-7-2014","HoraConsulta":"14:41"....}]}

```
  <?php
       $host     = "XXXXX";
       $username = "XXXXX";
       $password = "XXXXX";
       $db_name  = "android";

       $con = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect");
       mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("cannot select DB");
       $tec    = $_POST['Tecnica'];
       $sql    = "select * from info order by Registo desc";
       $result = mysql_query($sql);
       $json   = array();

       if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           $json['info'][] = $row;
       }
      }
     mysql_close($con);
     echo json_encode($json);
   ?>
```

Codigo PhP que quero por a funcionar(objetivo: so mostrar a informação da pessoa que faz log in):
O PROBLEMA deste codigo é que não me envia nada para o android. O log:
jsonResult:﹕  []

```
      <?php
      $host     = "XXXXX";
      $username = "XXXXXX";
       $password = "XXXXXX";
      $db_name  = "android";

       $con = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect");
      mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("cannot select DB");
      $tec    = $_POST['Tecnica'];
      $sql    = "select * from info where Tecnica = $tec order by Registo desc";
      $result = mysql_query($sql);
      $json   = array();

       if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $json['info'][] = $row;
        }
         }
        mysql_close($con);
         echo json_encode($json);
       ?>
```

E a minha classe (sem mudar a classe, funciona o 1º php mas nao o segundo):

public class ReadInfo extends Activity {

```
ListAdapter adapter;
String NTECNICA;
private String jsonResult;
private String url = "http://www.cresceranorte.com/WebService/info.php";
private ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.read_info);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        NTECNICA=  intent.getExtras().getString("NTECNICA");
        Log.d("Atencao NTecnica", NTECNICA);

        //Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    accessWebService();

}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
public void addInfo(View v)
        {
                Intent i = new Intent(ReadInfo.this, AddInfo.class);

            i.putExtra("NTECNICA",NTECNICA);
                startActivity(i);
            }


public void actList(View v)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(ReadInfo.this, ReadInfo.class);
    startActivity(i);
}




// Async Task to access the web
public class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        String post_Tecnica=NTECNICA;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet ger = new HttpGet(url);
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Tecnica", post_Tecnica));

        String oo;
        oo = String.valueOf(nameValuePairs);
        Log.d("HTTP: ", oo);
        try {

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(ger);

            oo = String.valueOf(response);
            Log.d("HTTPResponse: ", oo);
            jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            Log.d("Atencao jsonResult: ", jsonResult);

        }

        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String rLine = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        try {
            while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(rLine);
            }
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        return answer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        ListDrwaer();
    }
}// end async task

public void accessWebService() {
    JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
    // passes values for the urls string array
    task.execute(new String[] { url });
}

// build hash set for list view
public void ListDrwaer() {

    List<Map<String, String>> consultasList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();


    try {

        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
        JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("info");


        for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = jsonChildNode.optString("NProcesso");
            String number = jsonChildNode.optString("DataConsulta");
            String dat = jsonChildNode.optString("HoraConsulta");
            String outPut = "Nº Processo: "+ name + "\n" + "Data: "+ number + "\n" + "Hora: "+ dat + "\n";
            consultasList.add(createEmployee("employ", outPut));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error ListDrwaer " + e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("Error ListDrwaer  ", e.toString());
    }

    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, consultasList,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            new String[] { "employ" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
}

private HashMap<String, String> createEmployee(String name, String number) {
    HashMap<String, String> employeeNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
    employeeNameNo.put(name, number);
    return employeeNameNo;
}
```

}

Comment: O "erro" está evidentemente na query, pelo visto o parâmetro que você passou no segundo código faz com que a query não encontre nenhuma entrada com estes requisitos, o que faz a consulta voltar vazia. Tente verificar se a variável `$tec` não é nula, e também se essa sua consulta retorna alguma coisa se testada direto no console do MySQL.

Comment: Além disso, evite usar `mysql_query()`, ainda mais quando você passa variáveis direto na consulta. Esta função está deprecada e possui brechas de segurança. Procure utilizar [`Mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php) ou [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php) no lugar dela.

Comment: Como disseste o mais provavel é a variavel $tec estar vazia o problema é que eu andei 1 dia a ver isto mas simplesmente não sei onde é que errei na classe. Esta classe é a junção de outras 2, a original que servia para ler a informação da tabela toda e outra classe que eu uso para inserir valores.

Comment: Tentei usar a classe que envia valores para a tabela para simplesmente enviar uma variavel para fazer o where mas parece que não é assim tão simples

Answer (score 1):

Sua consulta SQL não está escapando a variável, se ela for uma string, isso pode estar causando problemas na hora do banco executar a consulta.

Mude para:

```
$sql=sprintf("select * from info where Tecnica = '%s' order by Registo desc", $tec);
```

Além disso, o grupo de funções `mysql_*` é precário e inseguro. Use o grupo `mysqli_*` ou a classe PDO.

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta mas não é esse o problema eu insiro isso no php mas da-me o mesmo erro.